# AJAX erro, não envia os dados

Tags: ajax

Não entendi ainda porque não envia via POST os dados no AJAX, vai direto para o error, e abre o Modal dizendo que houve o erro e rapidamente direciona para a página, mesmo esse modal não sendo para isso... Coloquei o Alert e ele faz a mesma coisa, abre o Alert de Error e direciona para página...

Preciso entender sobre essa situação para enviar meus dados via POST e ajax

```js
$(document).on("click", '#updateStatusEquip', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data:  { value_id : $('#admin_id').val() },      
      success: function(data) {
      // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
        console.log(data);
        
        $(".modal-body-info").html("Sucesso: Status do Registro alterado com sucesso");
        $("#myModalMessage").modal("show");
      },
      error: function () {
        $(".modal-title").html("Erro");
        $(".modal-body-info").html("Erro: Registro não foi inserido");
        $("#myModalMessage").modal("show");
      }
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal - Message -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalMessage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalMessage">
 <form method="post" id="ze-form" >
 
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" id="reloadTable" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-body-info">
        <b>Registro de:</b><br>Jonhy<input type="hidden" name="admin_id" id="admin_id" value="2"><br><b>Têm certeza que deseja alterar o status desse registro?</b><br>Poderá não ser capaz de acessar o Sistema</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="reloadTable" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <div class="modal-footer-button"><button type="submit" name="updateStatusEquip" id="updateStatusEquip" title="Alterar..." class="btn btn-warning">Alterar <i class="fas fa-level-up-alt ze-icon-m"></i><i class="fas fa-level-down-alt ze-icon-m"></i> </button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, eu acho que você esqueceu de informar a url do envio dos dados

Comment: Mas para evitar criar diversos php... queria que fosse na mesma página... onde abre o modal dentro do sucess, eu colocar um insert em php com a condição isset do valor em POST

Comment: Você deve informar a url pra onde esses dados serão enviados... Se você quer enviar para a mesma URL, informe a url que você está.

Comment: Mesmo adicionada, nada mudou....
url: 'index.php?page=equipList',

Comment: Então acho melhor você informar outra url para que esses dados sejam enviados, ficaria mais organizado e acredito que não quebraria tanto a cabeça como esse...

Comment: O que estou verificando que mesmo com outra URL conforme propos, não vai para o Sucess...
Os parametros estão sendo enviado, mas está sendo direcionado para o erro, e mesmo com alert, ele abre o alert e direciona rapidamente para a página principal... Acho que deve estár relacionado aos arquivos .jS da página, pois não vejo outra explicação... já utilizei $.post também e outros modelos... Será que têm haver com jquery que utilizo? 3.4.1?
Apesar que todas as outras funções, tudo funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Envio com ajax(1) e com form(2)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['value_id'])){
    echo $_POST['value_id'];
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Post Ajax to Same Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="admin_id" value="2" />
        <button type="submit">Via form</button>
    </form><br>

    <button id="buttonAjax">Via ajax</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        //1
        $(document).on("click", "#buttonAjax", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:  { value_id : $('#admin_id').val() },      
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });   
        });

        //2
        $(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function(event) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:  { value_id : $('#admin_id').val() },      
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });

            event.preventDefault();

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### 1

Note que você está tentando enviar com ajax, mas o button com `id="updateStatusEquip"` está dentro de um form com o `method="post"` e esse button tem o `type="submit"`. Ou seja, possivelmente o erro ocorre por está tentando enviar duas requisições POST simultaneamente, sendo uma via formulário e outra via ajax.

### 2

Se a origem dos dados enviados é um modal, você pode deixar o `type="submit"` no button dentro do form do modal e **fazer seu javascript capturar o evento de submit do form**, só que você vai parar esse evento, com `event.preventDefault()` e criar uma requisição ajax como antes. Isso irá permitir que envie os dados e prevenir o refresh da página.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus,
Estou ajustando e entendi, mas o   e.preventDefault(); coloco como e aonde? Desculpe mas sou iniciando na programação Java Script

Comment: Você coloca da mesma forma que eu usei no código acima. Modifiquei o código de modo a exemplificar para você. Testei e está funcionando das duas formas: com ajax diretamente e com o form. Repare o código abaixo do //2.

Comment: Matheus, 
Outra questão que mesmo no seu não funcionou... Vejo no navegador que o valor corre no POST, porém não captura no PHP... Sabe me dizer porque?
Acredito que seja algo entre a forma de envio antes de entrar no ajax... A saída vai para sucess e quando entra não captura o valor...

Comment: O que quer dizer exatamente com "porém não captura no PHP"? Se você modificar o trecho do meu código "echo $_POST['value_id'];" para "echo $_POST['value_id'] + 2;" no caso de enviar um valor numérico no value_id irá perceber que no success do javascript irá retornar o valor passado + 2. Isso significa que consegue fazer uma operação processada pelo PHP. É isso? Se a resposta foi útil para a sua dúvida inicial, dê um voto positivo, por favor.

Comment: O que eu desejo é colocar um IF de php depois do sucess capturando o value_id, assim evito ficar criando vários arquivos phps para cada envio que tenho que fazer...

Logo, vejo que o valor correu no console "value_id=13" por exemplo, mas no PHP, isset($_POST... não "capturou" esse valor... então não executa a função de alteração no BD... Entendeu?

Vou colocar como está para você entender

Utilizando url no ajax funciona... mas não desejo assim...

Comment: Cara, você não deve misturar javascript e php assim. O código fica inelegível. Como alguns já colocaram, o correto, de fato, seria separar seu código de html como links, menus, texto e modais do seu código php e também do seu código javascript em arquivos DISTINTOS. Mas sem problemas, depois procure por Separation of Concerns. Pelo que entendi você quer excluir um registro do banco de dados que tem o id enviado. Você deverá mover todo o código php para o topo do arquivo, conforme meu exemplo, e dar um "echo" em alguma variável que vai dizer se a operação no BD ocorreu com sucesso ou não.

Comment: Esse retorno do "echo" do php, vai estar na variavel data no success do javascript. Com ela(variavel data), você consegue fazer os IFS e ELSES, no próprio javascript, para definir o que será exibido ou não para o usuário, como o preenchimento que está fazendo dessa forma: "$(".modal-body-info").html()". Entende?

Comment: Eu entendo que devemos separar, mas se o valor recebido for em POST e o PHP pegar esse valor quando ele for enviado, acredito não ter problemas..
Mas qualquer coisa vou tem que criar diversos arquivos phps de envio para trabalhar com ajax...Isso mesmo que disse no último comentário, preciso pegar o valor do "data" que vem do AJAX e assim em o $_POST captura ele, e assim executa o PHP...
Vai facilitar muito o tempo de programação do restando do sistema que desejo...
Estou utilizando o mesmo Modal para todas as ações, logo terminando esse "modelo", o restante ficará fácil de fazer

Comment: Por exemplo, aquele prevent do java coloquei assim... ficou mais prático... e deu certo...
  $("#defaultForm").submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Então,

Consegui assim, porém a página faz o refresh... e apenas utilizando o Alert... Quando coloco para abrir um Modal, dá erro... deve estar outra coisa errada.

Mesmo tirando o type do button (submit)... após o Alert de Sucesso ele dá o refresh na página... Como resolvo isso?

```js
// AJAX - Alterar Status

$(document).on("click", '#updateStatusEquip', function() {

  // dados de exemplo
  var dados = {
    admin_id: $('#admin_id').val(),
  }

  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "php_action/updateStatusEquip.php",
    data : dados, 
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'html',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Cadastrado com sucesso!");
    },

    error: function(error) {
      alert("Erro ao tentar realizar o cadastro!");
    }    
  });   
});
// AJAX - Alterar Status - End
```

Answer (score 0):

Matheus,

```js
 // AJAX - Deletar
  $(document).on("click", "#deleteEquip", function() {

    var dados = {
      buttonAcess: $('#acessDeleteEquip').val(),
      value_id: $('#admin_id').val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data:  dados,
      async : true,
      cache : false,
      dataType : 'html',
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",      
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        table.ajax.reload();      
        $('.modal-title').html('Deletar');
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST) && !empty(utf8_decode($_POST['buttonAcess']))){
            
          $update = $datasource->deleteEquip($_POST['value_id']);
            
          if ($update) {                        
          ?>        
            $(".modal-body-info").html("<div class='alert alert-success ze-center'>Registro deletado com sucesso<br><i class='fas fa-thumbs-up ze-icon-g'></i></div>");     
          <?php }
          else{ ?>
            $(".modal-body-info").html("<div class='alert alert-danger ze-center'>Erro: Envio [1] (PHP)<br><i class='fas fa-thumbs-down ze-icon-g'></i></div>");     
          <?php
          }
        }
        else{ ?>
          $(".modal-body-info").html("<div class='alert alert-danger ze-center'>Erro: Envio [2] (PHP)<br><i class='fas fa-thumbs-down ze-icon-g'></i><?php echo $_POST['value_id']; ?></div>");
        <?php } ?>

        $('.modal-footer-button').html('');
        $("#myModalMessage").modal("show");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        $('.modal-title').html('Deletar');
        $(".modal-body-info").html("<div class='alert alert-danger ze-center'>Erro: Envio [3] (AJAX)<br><i class='fas fa-thumbs-down ze-icon-g'></i></div>");     
        $('.modal-footer-button').html('');
        $("#myModalMessage").modal("show");
      }    
    });
  });
  // AJAX - Deletar - End
```